# Making a lot of chained API calls in Apex

Tags: apex, callout, queueable-apex

I'm supposed to make around 1500 chained API calls in apex. This is the process: I want to get a list of courses of a semester from an external server, then for each course, I want to make a separate API call that gets the meeting dates of that particular course-which is an array of data. Then for each item of that array, I need to make an API call to get the room name, and another API call to get the building name of that meeting day. So overall, I'll be having around 1500 API calls.
I've used Queueables, but SF is giving me an error saying "too many queueable jobs added to the queue". I also wanted to use the Batch classes instead, but I realized they are used for the cases that we're processing SF records, while I'm not.

I can share my code here for more clarity:

```java
public static void fetchAndStoreSemestersData(){
    System.enqueueJob(new ExcClassSectionTermsQueueable('October2023'));
}
```

Here's the first Queueable class:

```java
public class ExcClassSectionTermsQueueable implements Queueable, Database.AllowsCallouts{
    
    private String termName;
    private List<Object> coursesArray;
    private String courseType, ...;
    
    //data from the MeetingScheduleDay endpoint
    private String meetingDate, startTime, endTime, dayOfWeek;
    
    public ExcClassSectionTermsQueueable(String termName) {
        this.termName = termName;
    }
    
    public void execute(QueueableContext context) {

        //making the first API call
        coursesArray = (List<Object>)CVWebEndpoints.GET_ClassSectionTerms(termName);  
        processTheResponse();
        
    }
    
    public void processTheResponse() {
        
        if (!coursesArray.isEmpty()) {
            ExcClassScheduleStatics.coursesArraySize = coursesArray.size();
            for (Object course : coursesArray) {
                
                // cast "courses" to a map so we can access its properties
                Map<String, Object> courseData = (Map<String, Object>) course;
                String courseCode = (String) ((Map<String, Object>)courseData.get('ClassSection')).get('CourseCode');
                courseType = ExcClassSchedulesHelper.getCourseType(courseCode);
                ...

                CourseObj courseObj = new CourseObj();
                courseObj.courseType = courseType;
                ...
                
                if(courseType!='Online'){
                    
                    System.enqueueJob(new ExcMeetingScheduleDayQueueble(courseObj));
                }       
               
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Here's the second Queueable class:

```java
public class ExcMeetingScheduleDayQueueble implements Queueable, Database.AllowsCallouts{
    
    private CourseObj courseObj;
    private List<Object> classSectionMeetingScheduleDayArray;
    
    
    public ExcMeetingScheduleDayQueueble(CourseObj courseObj) {
        this.courseObj = courseObj;
    }
    
    public void execute(QueueableContext context) {

        //making the second API call
        classSectionMeetingScheduleDayArray = (List<Object>)CVWebEndpoints.GET_ClassSectionMeetingScheduleDay(courseObj.classSectionId);
        processTheResponse();
    }
    
    public void processTheResponse() {
        
        if (!classSectionMeetingScheduleDayArray.isEmpty()) {
            for (Object meetingSchedule : classSectionMeetingScheduleDayArray) {
                
                System.enqueueJob(new ExcBuildingQueueble(courseObj, buildingId, roomId)); 
                
            }  
        }
    }
}
```

This is the third Queueable class:

```java
public class ExcBuildingQueueble implements Queueable, Database.AllowsCallouts{
    
    private CourseObj courseObj;
    private List<Object> buildingArray;
    private Integer buildingId;
    private Integer roomId;
    
    public ExcBuildingQueueble(CourseObj courseObj, Integer buildingId, Integer roomId) {
        this.courseObj = courseObj;
        this.buildingId = buildingId;
        this.roomId = roomId;
    }
    
    public void execute(QueueableContext context) {

        //making the third API call
        buildingArray = (List<Object>)CVWebEndpoints.GET_Building(buildingId);
        processTheResponse();
    }
    
    public void processTheResponse() {
        if(!buildingArray.isEmpty()){
            Map<String, Object> buildingData = (Map<String, Object>) buildingArray[0];
            if((String)(buildingData.get('Name'))!=null && (String)(buildingData.get('Name'))!=''){
                String building = (String)(buildingData.get('Name'));
                courseObj.buildingName = building;
            }
            
        }
        
        System.enqueueJob(new ExcRoomQueueble(courseObj, roomId));
        
    }
}
```

And finally this is the forth:

```java
public class ExcRoomQueueble implements Queueable, Database.AllowsCallouts{
    
    private CourseObj courseObj;
    private List<Object> roomArray;
    private Integer roomId;
    
    public ExcRoomQueueble (CourseObj courseObj, Integer roomId) {
        this.courseObj = courseObj;
        this.roomId = roomId;
    }
    
    public void execute(QueueableContext context) {

        //making the forth API call
        roomArray = (List<Object>)CVWebEndpoints.GET_Room(roomId);
        processTheResponse();
    }
    
    public void processTheResponse() {
        if(!roomArray.isEmpty()){
            
            Map<String, Object> roomData = (Map<String, Object>) roomArray[0];
            if((String)(roomData.get('Name'))!=null && 
               (String)(roomData.get('Name'))!='' && 
               (String)(roomData.get('RoomNumber'))!=null && 
               (String)(roomData.get('RoomNumber'))!=''){
                   String room = (String)(roomData.get('Name')) + ' - '+(String)(roomData.get('RoomNumber'));
                   courseObj.roomName = room;
               }
        }
      
    }
}
```

(I tried to make the code as brief as possible). Anyone has any idea? I'd appreciate any help.

Comment: This small lib I made might not solve all your problems but some of them https://github.com/rsoesemann/apex-chainable

Comment: I would recommend talking to whoever owns the external system; they may support alternative options. Having to separately query the building and room is not a good REST or Web Service API design - that is the sort of thing you would do where there is no network involved. It would also be appropriate for them to provide some form of bulk access API.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can query the external API for the first header data, create Salesforce records for those, and then use a batch job to iterate those records and do your multiple callouts for each piece of data.

So in this scenario:

```
courses > meetings > room
```

I'm assuming you could either query the courses and store that as a custom object, or query both courses and meetings for each course on the same or few callouts, store that as a master-detail relationship, and then you could have a batch for the rooms.

Comment: Thanks for your response Renato! Do batch classes not have any limitations like Queueables? Because even if I want to save the courses in SF and go over each record and make API calls for room and building, there still will be a lot of API calls.

Comment: Not if you do things the way I described. You wouldn't be adding new jobs to the queue. The callouts would be made in the batch context, which has its governor limits reset after each iteration too.

Comment: Thank you so much for your idea,I implemented what you suggested and it's working well. First, I'm saving a list of courses in a custom object, and then for each record, I'm making an API call using a Batch class. But I'm having an issue, SF has the limit of 100 API calls per transaction; while I have 350 records saved in my custom object and for each record I need a separate API call. Do you have any idea how I can get around it? (please note that the current Batch size is 1 and I cannot increase it, because the external server that I'm sending the API requests to, doesn't accept bulk inputs)

Comment: Then do another batch on those after the first batch is completed. So you can process each record individually with a batch of size 1.

Comment: I set the Batch Size to 100 to make sure that no more than 100 API calls will be made in one execute run, and now it's working well. Thank you so much for your help Renato!